# How to create a link in javascript with laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

can someone help me on how I can create a link in Javascript with Laravel.
Or how can I convert this code to javascript?("{{ route('blog.single', $post->slug) }}") because I wanted to show the URL of every single post I have used in that code, I don't know what's wrong but the URL only shows me the last post that I have created, when everytime I click the VIEW button the one that keeps on showing is the slug/url in the last post I created.

This is my code for getting the slug in database

```
 data-slug="{{$post->slug}}"
```

This is my code in passing it using jQuery.

$(document).on('click', '.show-post', function() {

```
  var slug = $(this).attr('data-slug');
   $('#show-slug').html(slug);
   $('.show-single-post').css('display','block');
   $('.posts-table').css('display','none');
```

});

And my code for creating the URL.

```
{{ route('blog.single', $post->slug) }}
```

The blog.single, is my single.blade.php that shows the single post.

Comment: what u have tried? and what is ur expected result?

Comment: what is file name ? is it `.blade.php` ?

Comment: yes the file name is .blade.php

Comment: This is what I expected with that link " http://blog.com/blog/example-slug " @arun

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var route = {{ route('blog.single', $post->slug) }};
alert(route);
<script>
```

Comment: Make sure to put this in your blade file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   url: '{{ route('blog.single', $post->slug) }}'


...
```

I think thats you want. If its not comment below.